# How to find a header path in a cpp file ROS

Tags: c++, gcc, header, ubuntu-16.04, ros

I am learning how to program in ros. And the first difficulty for me is the header files. I want to read the original code, but the question is where are they? How do I locate those header files?

I have tried `gcc -H xx.cpp` in the current path, but it just show me some  irrelevent answer. For example, I am curious about ros.h, not string. For ros.h, it tells me

```
fatal error: ros/ros.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated.
```

I have no idea now.

```
dale@dale-Aspire-EC-471G:~/Compile/src/learningros/chapter8_tutorials/src$ gcc -H tf_broadcaster.cpp 
tf_broadcaster.cpp:1:21: fatal error: ros/ros.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

dale@dale-Aspire-EC-471G:~/Compile/src/learningros/chapter8_tutorials/src$ gcc -H odometry.cpp 
. /usr/include/c++/5/string
.. /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/5/bits/c++config.h
... /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/5/bits/os_defines.h
.... /usr/include/features.h
..... /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/cdefs.h
...... /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/wordsize.h
..... /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/gnu/stubs.h
...... /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/gnu/stubs-64.h
..............
........ /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/include/stddef.h
........ /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/time.h
......... /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/timex.h
....... /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/pthreadtypes.h
........ /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/wordsize.h
....... /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/setjmp.h
........ /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/wordsize.h
....... /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/wordsize.h
.... /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/5/bits/atomic_word.h
... /usr/include/c++/5/ext/alloc_traits.h
.. /usr/include/c++/5/bits/basic_string.tcc
odometry.cpp:2:21: fatal error: ros/ros.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

I expect to find a efficient way to find the header in a cpp file tht I want to know. Hope you can help or give me some advice.

Comment: Check the environment variable `ROS_ROOT`. This should be the installation path of ros: http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/EnvironmentVariables

Answer (score 1):

The command `gcc -H odometry.cpp` will list all the paths that gcc is searching for header files. Since as the previous command gave an error saying it couldn't find this header this list will not include the location, otherwise the previous command would have found `ros/ros.h` and not produced that error.

The location of these header files in a standard ROS install will be:

```
/opt/ros/<distribution_name>/include
```

The path to these header files will be setup for you automatically if you've run the setup script `source /opt/ros/<distribution_name>/setup.bash` or included it in your `.bashrc` script.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Er, but I had added "source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash" to ~/.bashrc since I learned ros and it would't be a mistake when I run those cpp files. Actually, I pay more attention to how to find a header in ros.